How to represent discriminated union in pydantic-settings?
My project has two ways to be run: webhook and polling. Therefore, it requires two different configs depends on a running type. I construct config from environment variables, where RUN_TYPE variable (either "webhook" or "polling") discriminates a run type. Each run type requires different set of variables.
Here is my attempt to represent it with pydantic/pydantic-settings:
class WebhookSettings(BaseModel):
    run_type: Literal["webhook"]
    webhook_url: str
    webhook_path: str

class PollingSettings(BaseModel):
    run_type: Literal["polling"]
    polling_interval: int

class RunSettings(BaseSettings):
    run: Annotated[Union[WebhookSettings, PollingSettings], Field(discriminator="run_type")]

But when I run it with environment: RUN_TYPE="polling" POLLING_INTERVAL=15, it fails:
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for RunSettings
run
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/missing

What is my problem?

You are using nested settings, so you need to set it properly:
class WebhookSettings(BaseModel):
    run_type: Literal["webhook"]
    webhook_url: str
    webhook_path: str

class PollingSettings(BaseModel):
    run_type: Literal["polling"]
    polling_interval: int

class RunSettings(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_nested_delimiter="__")

    run: Annotated[Union[WebhookSettings, PollingSettings], Field(discriminator="run_type")]

For webhook settings:
os.environ["run__run_type"] = "webhook"
os.environ["run__webhook_url"] = "http://test.com"
os.environ["run__webhook_path"] = "v1/tests"

settings = RunSettings()

print(settings.model_dump())
# {'run': {'run_type': 'webhook', 'webhook_url': 'http://test.com', 'webhook_path': 'v1/tests'}}

Polling settings:
os.environ["run__run_type"] = "polling"
os.environ["run__polling_interval"] = "10"

settings = RunSettings()

print(settings.model_dump())
# {'run': {'run_type': 'polling', 'polling_interval': 10}}

